# Reveal.js - how to change progress bar width

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I am a newbie to JS and reveal.js. I would like to make the progress bar thicker, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the CSS (or SCSS if you want) file for your theme and specify the height for your progress bar. You can search for `.progress` in the theme `css` file. Here's what mine looks like after specifying the height.

```css
/*********************************************
 * PROGRESS BAR
 *********************************************/
.reveal .progress {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #7e588aff;
  height: 1%;
}
```

I'm pretty new to js and reveal.js as well, so this may not be the best way to do this, but it's worked well in my personal presentations.